# How to check if a Helm release exists before running the helm uninstall command

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kubernetes-helm

I want to add a condition in helm uninstall command in Azure devops pipeline if only a release(infra) is already there i want to uninstall it. How can i do that?

```
- task: HelmDeploy@0
        displayName: Helm uninstall test
        inputs:
          connectionType: Kubernetes Service Connection
          kubernetesServiceEndpoint: dev-test
          command: uninstall
          chartType: FilePath
          chartPath: infra
          waitForExecution: true
          namespace: test
          arguments: infra
        continueOnError: true
```

Comment: The fragment you show doesn't look like something I'd normally see in a Helm chart; what tool is it?  It looks like you're uninstalling the chart and ignoring errors, which should have the effect of uninstalling the chart if it's installed and continuing otherwise; what do you hope to happen differently?

Comment: Yea sorry it is a part of Azure devops pipeline script. Yea it uninstalls chart and ignores error but i want to have a pre-condition to check it is already deployed or not. Because the pipeline does not look green(success) if there is no chart as infra it shows with orange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OLD ANSWER**

What you're basically trying to achieve is to have an exit code for your command that is equal to 0. Generally, you could do the following to achieve this behavior:

```bash
helm uninstall <MY_RELEASE_NAME> -n my-k8s-namespace || true
```

In this case, the exit code for your command will always be 0, even if the helm uninstall command exits with a different exit code when the given release does not exist, which would be 1 in your case.

To check the exit code for a previous command, do the following:

```bash
# try uninstalling a non existing release
helm uninstall <NON_EXISTING_RELEASE_NAME> -n my-k8s-namespace

# check the exit code for that previous command
echo $?
```

This returns 1 if the helm release does not exist in the given k8s namespace.

**NEW ANSWER**

I updated by answer based on your comment. What you could do is the following:

```bash
helm status <MY_RELEASE_NAME> && helm uninstall <MY_RELEASE_NAME>
```

When using the `&&` operator, a command following this operator is only executed if the command which precedes it succeeds. Hence, your Helm release would only be uninstalled when the preceding `helm status <my_release_name>` commands returns an exit code which equals to 0 (which means a Helm release with the given name was found). Though, this might break your CI/CD pipeline (job) as the `helm status <my_release_name>` commands returns a non-zero exit code when not finding a release matching the given name. In order to avoid that, you go a step further and do this:

```bash
helm status <MY_RELEASE_NAME> && helm uninstall <MY_RELEASE_NAME> || true
```

Doing so, the exit code of the above expression would be 0 even if the `helm status` or `helm uninstall` command fails to find a Helm release with the given name.

The answer was inspired by the accepted answer of [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208870/how-do-i-run-a-command-only-after-previous-command-is-unsuccessful-in-bash).

Comment: thank you for your response but  i want to have a precondition before run the helm uninstall command if the release exısts then i want to run helm uninstall command

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment. I hope this helps in what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to pass `--ignore-not-found` option to `helm uninstall` command (see official docs).

Like this:

```
helm uninstall <MY_RELEASE_NAME> -n <MY_K8S-NAMESPACE> --ignore-not-found
```

Comment: `--ignore-not-found` has been added in helm 3.13.0

Comment: simplest and best approach for latest version of helm